# Vba Update Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Im designing a macro that will take two sheets, an original and one to be updated from the original.  It takes the original and copies the sheet and sorts everything by a key. It also unhides and unfilters the data so that all the keys are in order.  All of this works except the sheet to be updated does not become unfiltered and I can't see why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub crossUpdate()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng1Row As Range, rng2Row As Range, Key As Range, match As Integer

Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm").Activate

'Unhide and Unfilter columns and rows on original sheet
 Sheet3.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Sheet3.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Sheet3.Cells.AutoFilter

'Copy and paste original sheet to new temp sheet
Sheet3.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "SourceData"
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Sort temp sheet by key
 N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = Sheets("SourceData").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng1Row = rng1.EntireRow
rng1Row.Sort Key1:=Sheets("SourceData").Range("A1")


Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2 ESI.xlsm").Activate
'Unhide and Unfilter columns and rows on update sheet
Sheet3.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Sheet3.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Sheet3.AutoFilterMode = False

'Update sheet sorted by key
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells.Range("A2:A" & N)
Set rng2Row = rng2.EntireRow
rng2Row.Sort Key1:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: when you reference things like Sheets it is referencing the active sheet.  Try appending the objects with the worksheet object.

Comment: so do something like this to all the lines? `Workbooks("011 High Level Task List v2.xlsm").Sheet3.Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False`